# How to connect Ethernet Magnetic/RJ45

Tags: ethernet, magnetics, phy, rj45

I am connecting up my PHY to an RJ45 with magnetics and was wondering what I do with some pins on it.

Here is the circuit for the Rj45 w/ magnetics.
My questions are:

1. do I connect pin 10 to the chassis GND?
2. What do I connect 4,5,7,and 8?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 No, that magjack does not support POE.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 But the magjack cable side has DC coupled "Bob Smith" termination with 75 ohms. POE source would detect it as invalid signature and refuse to give power to avoid damage. Forcing 48V would fry the resistors in the magjack. And there's no cable side center taps to connect power in or out of the cable side.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 That's a magjack, a potted connector module with integrated transformer. You don't have access to the cable side, right side 8 pins are directly the actual RJ45 socket prongs, so you can't ground pin 8 of the cable side. The 12 pins you can connect yourself on PCB are on the left.

Comment: So the 75 ohms just lower the CM impedance of the unused lines for 4,5,7,8

Answer (score 4):

Pin 10 connects to chassis, yes.

Pins 4,5,7,8 of the cable side connects to cabling via 8P8C connector. You can't and don't have to do anything about those pins.

Unless you mean pins 4,5,7,8 at the PHY side, in which case you connect them how PHY requires them to be connected.

Comment: @Justme. Ok thanks now I see it. one side (on left) will be connected to the PC board. The other pins on the right are parts of the RJ45 and I don't connect them at all. The PCB layout diagram shows a 12 pins to connect to the PCB board